# bash. Exata symbols when parsing file in cycle

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, cycle

Please, help me with one simple script on bash. I wrote a script to backup one server with many vhosts. This script works fine, except one config file. When script parses this file, in results it adds some extra symbols 
Cycle of parsing

```
for n in `find /etc/nginx/conf.d/ -type f -name *.conf`
        do
                dir_for_bckp=`cat $n | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | egrep "^root" | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/\;//g'`
                name_bckp=`echo $dir_for_bckp | sed 's/\//\_/g'`
                tar -zcvf $tmp_dir/backup/$name_bckp.tar.gz $dir_for_bckp/ 1>/dev/null
        done
```

Output for problematic file in debug mode

```
+ for n in '`find /etc/nginx/conf.d/ -type f -name *.conf`'
++ cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/gitlab.conf
++ awk '{ print $1,$2 }'
++ awk '{ print $2 }'
++ sed 's/\;//g'
++ egrep '^root'
+ dir_for_bckp=$'/home/git/gitlab/public\r'
++ sed 's/\//\_/g'
+ name_bckp=$'_home_git_gitlab_public\r'
```

My question - why *dir_for_bckp=$'/home/git/gitlab/public\r'* ? Must be *dir_for_bckp=/home/git/gitlab/public* 
Parsing other config files is ok!
Example

```
+ for n in '`find /etc/nginx/conf.d/ -type f -name *.conf`'
++ cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/site-com.conf
++ awk '{ print $1,$2 }'
++ egrep '^root'
++ sed 's/\;//g'
++ awk '{ print $2 }'
+ dir_for_bckp=/home/site.com/html
++ sed 's/\//\_/g'
+ name_bckp=_home_site.com_html
```

If I manually parse problematic file, output also ok.

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/gitlab.conf | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | egrep "^root" | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/\;//g'
/home/git/gitlab/public
```

Comment: Note `cat $n | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | egrep "^root" | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/\;//g'` is inefficient. You have [\[ useless use of cat \]](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Try consummating the whole objeective using a single `awk` script. I'm sure that is possible but a bit lazy to write it for you ;)

Comment: Google UUOC, deprecated backticks, quote your variables, and read the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the config file was created with MSWindows line ends, i.e. each line ends with `\r\n`, not only `\n`. Use `fromdos` or `dos2unix` to fix the file.